# weird sed doubling replacement

Tags: sed

When I use sed with the following recipe, I get a duplicated replacement

```bash
$ cat example.txt                                                 
id: "a/b/c/d"
id: "e/f/g/h"

# dry-run works as expected, good ! 
$ sed -n -e 's/id: \"\([^\"\/]*\)\/[^\"]*\"/id: \"\1\"/gp' example.txt
id: "a"
id: "e"

# let's do the actual replacement in place
$ sed -i'.original' -e 's/id: \"\([^\"\/]*\)\/[^\"]*\"/id: \"\1\"/gp' example.txt

# wait, where did that duplicated line come from?
$ cat example.txt
id: "a"
id: "a"
id: "e"
id: "e"
```

Comment: You are missing the `-n` flag? The flag is need to indicate to print only the lines matching (or) affected

Comment: You mean add the `-n` flag to the actual replacement command?

Comment: A bit easier to read is `sed -Eni.original 's~(id: "[^/]*)[^"]*"~\1"~gp' example.txt`

Comment: Please explain your reasoning for using `-n` in the successfull dry-run, but not in the failing in-place version.

Comment: @Yunnosch I thought the `-n` flag is just to forbid sed from printing the entire file to stdout, and make it only print the changed lines - I guess I was wrong (?)

Comment: Sounds like you can create your own answer. Or you can prompt @Inian for one with a detailed explanation. Generally, if you have two differences between "works" and "fails" and you wonder endlessly why the first causes the problem - do not forget to check the second.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom sed is going to output the same stream whether it is redirected with `-i` or not.   The reason you need `-n` is because you have `s///p` substitution, which will print the pattern space (the line, after substitution) if the substitution happened.  So conceivably you could also remove the `p` from your `s///` and never use `-n`.  `s///p` is usually for duplication (as it causes in your case) or, when using `-n`, to select lines to print.